# IsType<T> and IsType(object, object) throwing IsTypeException

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

I am attempting to assert that an object being returned by a method call is of the type `List<MyClass>`, so using xUnit I have tried the following:

```
var expected = typeof(List<MyClass>);
var actual = typeof(method());

Assert.IsType<List<MyClass>>(actual);
Assert.IsType(expected, actial);
```

Both of the above throw the `IsTypeException` however if I perform:

```
var areSameType = expected == actual
```

`areSameType` is `true`.  So is there something going on deeper down that I am not accounting for?

Docs:

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/xunit.extensions/xunit.extensions/Assertions/M/IsType(T)
http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/xunit.extensions/xunit.extensions/Assertions/M/IsType

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first argument for Assert.IsType should be the object itself not its type, the following should not throw:

```
var expected = typeof(List<MyClass>);
var actual = Method();

Assert.IsType<List<MyClass>>(actual);
Assert.IsType(expected, actual);
```

Comment: You can also simplify that down to just lines 2 and 3, or 1, 2 and 4 (i.e. either creating the object as `expected` or just passing the type and `actual` together).

Comment: Sure, but the answer follows the question's pattern and is more readable IMHO