# Is there any way to resolve the Assert.Istype() failure Issue?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

When I Am writing `test_case` for `details_byId` the `Assert.Istype()` failure

```
[Fact]
public  void Get_DetailsbyId_NotFound()
{
    //ILoggerMocking

    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
   .AddLogging()
    .BuildServiceProvider();

    var factory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

    var logger = factory.CreateLogger<DetailsAPIController>();

    //Act
    detailsAPIController = new DetailsAPIController(detailsByIdTestCasePreparation.mockContext.Object, logger);
    //Arrange
    var res = detailsAPIController.GetDetails(22);
    //Assert
    Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(res);

}
```

GetDetailsMethod

```
[Route("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetDetails(int id)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Get details API called");

    try
    {
        return Ok(_detailsbyIdRepository.GetDetails(id));

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("An error was thrown because: "+ex.Message);
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

In the above the `Assert.IsType` is failure actual I'm trying to `bad_request` but it getting `OkObjectResult`

```
Expected: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult
Actual:  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult
```

Can any one help out form it

Comment: Maybe this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/26925780/8559155

Comment: Not working fr me..

Comment: Actually it should return bad request but it's returning OkObjectResult the Id which I passing is not there.

Comment: @jagadeesh No where in the code under test is a `NotFoundResult` returned, yet you have `Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(res);`. Based on the shown code the behavior you experience is as expected.

Comment: @Nkosi  : Is there any issue with my GetDetailsBy Method.?

Comment: @Nkosi : small issue in getdetails method code,I resolved and it's working now..Thank you